# how to use chrome.socket in javascript?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do I fix this error?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'socket' of undefined

It's Part of the background.js file

```
    var SocketId = 0;
    chrome.socket.connect(SocketId, '127.0.0.1', 5053, function(result) {
        console.log('socket connect, result : '+result+'');
        if(result === 0) {
            chrome.socket.write(SocketId, str2ap('client say : Hello'), function(writeInfo){
                console.log('socket write, writeInfo.bytesWritten : '+writeInfo.bytesWritten+'');
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: please don't bundle questions together, that seem to have no correlation.  SO is no forum but centered around Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is tagged [[image]google-chrome-extension](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension), so I assume you're trying to make an extension.

The Sockets API is only available for Chrome Apps:

[Chrome Extensions API list](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index)
[Chrome Apps API list](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index)

Both lists have some APIs exclusive to them. If you absolutely need socket communications, you have 4 possibilities:

1. Switch to a Chrome App. In many cases, this is not an option, since only extensions can interact with normal browser content. [Comparison between two](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/apps_vs_extensions) (slightly out of date, but applicable).
2. Make a companion App and require the user to install both. Then, communicate between them using [External Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external).
3. Make a native app (that can use whatever is available in the OS) and communicate with it using [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging). Heavy-handed approach similar to now-deprecated NPAPI, and it introduces troubles when distributing (you cannot bundle the native module in the Web Store, you need a separate installer), but ultimately the most powerful. See also [chrome-native-messaging](/questions/tagged/chrome-native-messaging)
4. Switch from using raw sockets to [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets) which are readily available to Extensions. This is only applicable if you want Chrome to initiate the connection, and if you control the server (you will need to rewrite it). However, this is the least invasive approach. If you do control the server, it's preferred.

   Alternatively, you can write a proxy server that accepts WebSocket connections and talks to your normal server on its behalf. There may be ready solutions of this type, now that I think about it. Edit: in fact, [there are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176344/websocket-relay).